# The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form in DRF 3

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

## OutputError

```
{
 "item_image": [
    "The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form."
],
"item_thumb": [
    "The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form."
]
}
```

Data which I'm posting is

## input

```
{
    "item_name": "Lural",
    "item_image": "/home/prashant/Desktop/suede.png",
    "item_thumb": "/home/prashant/Desktop/suede.png",
    "item_description": "sd",
    "item_mass": 1,
    "item_category": "Make Up",
    "item_sub_category": "Sub-Feminine",
    "item_est_price": "123.12",
    "item_wst_price": "120.34"
}
```

for media type application/json

## views.py

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def product_list(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = ProductSerializer( data=request.data)
        # data.encode("base64")
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            res_msg = {'Success_Message' : 'Created','Success_Code' : 201}
            return Response(res_msg)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

## models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    item_category_choices = (
        ('Make Up','Make Up'),
        ('Skin Care','Skin Care'),
        ('Fragrance','Fragrance'),
        ('Personal Care','Personal Care'),
        ('Hair Care','Hair Care'),
    )
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    item_image = models.ImageField()
    item_thumb = models.ImageField()
    item_description = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    item_mass = models.IntegerField()
    item_category = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices = item_category_choices)
    item_sub_category = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    item_est_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15,decimal_places=2)
    item_wst_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15,decimal_places=2)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.item_name or _('Sprint ending %s')% self.item_avg_price
```

## serializers.py

```
class ProductSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id','item_name' ,'item_image','item_thumb','item_description','item_mass','item_category',
              'item_sub_category','item_est_price','item_wst_price',)
```

tried many forums & third party packages too but their isn't any way out from this problem.
Also GET is working totally fine.

Thanks for your time

Comment: hey did you get the solution for this problem?

Comment: I'm also searching for a solution. Did anyone find one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Django Docs -

> If you intend to allow users to upload files, you must ensure that the
>   environment used to run Django is configured to work with non-ASCII
>   file names. If your environment isn’t configured correctly, you’ll
>   encounter UnicodeEncodeError exceptions when saving files with file
>   names that contain non-ASCII characters.

Thus adding this method to the model solved my problem :

```
class Product(models.Model):
item_category_choices = (
    ('Make Up','Make Up'),
    ('Skin Care','Skin Care'),
    ('Fragrance','Fragrance'),
    ('Personal Care','Personal Care'),
    ('Hair Care','Hair Care'),
    )
item_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,verbose_name='Product Name')
item_image = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Product Image')
item_thumb = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Product Thumb')
item_description = models.TextField(verbose_name='Product Descriptions')
item_mass = models.CharField(max_length=10,verbose_name='Product Weight')
item_category = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices = item_category_choices,verbose_name='Product Category')
item_sub_category = models.CharField(max_length=20,verbose_name='Product Sub Category')
item_est_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12,decimal_places=2,verbose_name='East Product Price')
item_wst_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12,decimal_places=2,verbose_name='West Product Price')
def __unicode__(self):
            return (self.item_name)
def image_img(self):
    if self.item_image:
        return u'<img src="%s" width="50" height="50" />' % self.item_image.url
    else:
        return '(Sin imagen)'
image_img.short_description = 'Thumb'
image_img.allow_tags = True
```

Comment: I still am getting this error :    `{"image":["Upload a valid image. The file you uploaded was either not an image or a corrupted image."]}`

Comment: Did you add the location of file in the content section of drf??

Comment: I have also checked the file system encoding in the python shell and it supports UFT-8 file names..

Comment: Have you added the path in urls, also try adding the image through admin and check if it working fine or not it should be.

Comment: This was a bug in DRF 2.4.4 and was fixed in 3.0 and its successor. Urls have to be added in urls.py image uploaded are usually added in media and their path is given in urls.

Comment: Please elaborate how can I do that?? Also I am getting another error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35953939/utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x89-in-position-15-invalid-start-byte . Please check this too.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of submitting a link to a file `"/home/prashant/Desktop/suede.png"`, you need to actually open the file and submit that instead.

For example, here is a test I have to test image submission:

```
 # generate image and open
tmp_file = Image.new('RGB', (3, 3,), 'white')
tmp_file.putpixel((1, 1,), 0)
tmp_file.save(f.name, format='PNG')
_file = open(f.name, 'rb')


data = {'file': _file}

response = api.client.put(url=url, data=data)
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer a bit more. It will be helpful.
Thanks

Comment: I tried your solution but response.status_code is 400, it should be 201

Comment: @djq How to add this in the content section of django rest framework?

Answer (score 1):

You should open the image and send the request as follows:

```
with open("/home/prashant/Desktop/suede.png", 'rb') as image:
    data = {'item_name': 'Lural',
            'item_image': image,
            'item_thumb': image,
            'item_description': 'sd',
            'item_mass': 1,
            'item_category': 'Make Up',
            'item_sub_category': 'Sub-Feminine',
            'item_est_price': '123.12',
            'item_wst_price': '120.34'
            }
    response = api.client.put(url, data, format='multipart')
```

This should work!

Comment: How to add this in the content section of django rest framework??

Comment: I am stuck in exactly same situation. you may see http://stackoverflow.com/q/35884951/5080347 as a reference. I have attached some snapshots for the django rest framework. In the content part of the drf I had added data in the same way as the OP of this question i.e I had given the location of the file in the image field and it didn't work. You suggested that the file needs to be open first and then send the request. I don't know how I can do that in drf i.e open the file in the content part and then send the request in the content part only. I hope I am clear now. :)

Comment: I don't want to add this piece of code in my views.py file. I want to send the raw data in django rest framework only. Thanx